# bash: IFS "stuck" after temporarily changing it for array building

Tags: bash, ifs

I've encountered a strange problem after temporarily changing `IFS` for the purpose of array building:

```sh
$ echo "1 2 3" |while read myVar1 myVar2; do echo "myVar1: ${myVar1}"; echo "myVar2: ${myVar2}"; done
myVar1: 1
myVar2: 2 3
$ IFS=':' myPaths=( ${PATH} )  # this works: I have /home/morgwai/bin on ${myPaths[0]} , /usr/local/sbin on ${myPaths[1]} and so on
$ echo "1 2 3" |while read myVar1 myVar2; do echo "myVar1: ${myVar1}"; echo "myVar2: ${myVar2}"; done
myVar1: 1 2 3
myVar2: 
$ echo $IFS

$ echo "1:2:3" |while read myVar1 myVar2; do echo "myVar1: ${myVar1}"; echo "myVar2: ${myVar2}"; done ;
myVar1: 1
myVar2: 2:3
```

Normally when I change `IFS` temporarily for any other command than array building (for example `IFS=',' echo whatever`) its value is changed only during the execution of that, however here it seems as if `IFS` got permanently changed to a colon (although `echo $IFS` doesn't show this, which is even more strange...).

Is this a bug or somehow an expected behavior that I don't understand?
I'm using bash version 4.4.18 if it matters...

*Note: I know that I can build the same array using `IFS=':' read -a myPaths <<< ${PATH}` and then `IFS` gets reverted to the default value normally, but that's not the point: I'm trying to understand what actually happens in the example I gave above.*

Thanks!

Comment: You're just setting variables, not setting a variable followed by executing a command.

Comment: @Shawn this would indeed explain why the change seems permanent, but why ```echo $IFS``` shows blank line instead of a colon?

Comment: BTW, I'd suggest `printf '%q\n' "$IFS"` to display the current value in a visually unambiguous form.

Comment: ...but yes, in the case of `IFS=':' myPaths=( ${PATH} )`, it's just two assignments, and _neither_ of them is temporary; there has to be an actual regular command on the line for the assignments preceding them to be treated as environment variables scoped to that command.

Comment: BTW, `array=( $content )` is not a good practice -- unless you disable globbing, it has potential to to do more things than just split on IFS. See [BashPitfalls #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#hosts.3D.28_.24.28aws_....29_.29).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy the way you edited my question makes it substantially different: I do not set ```IFS``` to coma in the beginning as you do in your edit and ```echo $IFS``` prints blank line, which is a important factor and something I'm hoping to get explanation for also

Comment: @Shawn I found the explanation for empty line on ```echo $IFS```, it's quite funny ;)  https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1454313

Comment: Btw, modern bash lets you use `${IFS@E}` or `${IFS@Q}` instead of that `printf` bit.

Comment: Gotcha. I tried to edit to clarify, but evidently didn't follow what you were trying to ask. (Which _does_ line up with the idea that clarification was needed).

Comment: (re: setting to a comma in the beginning, that was to have it at a known value, so we could compare against that known value later; in the original question, it was undefined what the value of `IFS` was expected to be).

Comment: Here is a good article on the topic: [IFS](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/IFS)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy yeah, in the end it turned out to be 2 separate issues, but initially I thought they were tightly related, hence the confusion: sorry for this. Anyway, thanks for your input and willingness to help :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're just setting variables, not setting a variable followed by executing a command (ie, the way you build array is a pure variable assignment, not a command, hence both assignments become permanent).

The issue with an `IFS` of `:` not showing up in `echo $IFS` is caused by shell parameter expansion and word splitting.

Consider:

```
$ IFS=:
$ echo $IFS

$ echo "$IFS"
:
```

When a parameter expansion is not quoted, it undergoes *word splitting* afterwords. From [the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Word-Splitting.html#Word-Splitting):

> The shell scans the results of parameter expansion, command substitution, and arithmetic expansion that did not occur within double quotes for word splitting.

and

> The shell treats each character of `$IFS` as a delimiter, and splits the results of the other expansions into words using these characters as field terminators. If IFS is unset, or its value is exactly `<space><tab><newline>`, the default, then sequences of `<space>`, `<tab>`, and `<newline>` at the beginning and end of the results of the previous expansions are ignored, and any sequence of IFS characters not at the beginning or end serves to delimit words.

So when `IFS` is a colon, splitting a word consisting of just a colon results in a (single) empty word. Always quote your variables to prevent unexpected gotchas like this.

Comment: Ahh. This would make the question a duplicate of [I just assigned a variable, but `echo $variable` prints something else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29378566/i-just-assigned-a-variable-but-echo-variable-shows-something-else).

Comment: this is exactly what is written in the link on ubuntuforums I've sent before  ;)(https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1454313 the last post, you need to scroll down). I'm upvoting your answer in recognition of your first initial comment on the question, which, while very simple, contained the answer to the main problem. If you care to put it in the beginning of your answer, I'll also mark it as accepted (in its current form the answer does not answer the main question, so it would be confusing for others to see it as accepted).